# Ajax does not see the function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-templates, django-views

There is a `CBV` (`JointProductsDetail`) that is responsible for rendering the template. In the template I am trying to execute an `ajax` request (`get` type). I specify the `url`. The request does not come to the specified function, but I get `success` in the response.

**template**

```
<form>
  <a href='#' class='add_to_cart'>
    <button class='btn btn-danger' id="make_an_order" type="button">abc</button>
  </a>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.add_to_cart').on('click', function(e){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "{% url 'add_to_cart' %}",
      data: {},
      success: function(data){
        alert('Товар добавлен в корзину');
        location.reload();
      },
      error: function(data){
        alert('Произошла ошибка. Попробуйте позже')
      }
    })
  })
})
</script>
```

**urls**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from products.views import (
    Categories, ProductsOrderStatus, ProductsOrderCancel,
    Products, ProductsCreate, ProductsDetail, ProductsUpdate,
    ProductsDelete, ProductsCopy, ProductsReport,
    JointProducts, JointProductsCreate, JointProductsDetail,
    JointProductsUpdate, JointProductsDelete, JointProductsCopy,
    JointProductsReport, add_to_cart_view, orders_week_view,
    orders_month_view, orders_year_view, bills_week_view,
    bills_month_view, bills_year_view, basket_view, cart_true_view,
    remove_cart_view, BillDetail, privat24
)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<section_slug>products|joint_products)/$',
        Categories.as_view(),
        name='products_categories_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<section_slug>products|joint_products)/orders/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/status/$',
        ProductsOrderStatus.as_view(),
        name='products_order_status'),
    url(r'^(?P<section_slug>products|joint_products)/orders/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/cancel/$',
        ProductsOrderCancel.as_view(),
        name='products_order_cancel'),
    url(r'^products/add/$', ProductsCreate.as_view(), name='products_create'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/add/$',
        ProductsCreate.as_view(),
        name='products_create'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        Products.as_view(),
        name='products_list'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        ProductsDetail.as_view(),
        name='products_detail'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/update/$',
        ProductsUpdate.as_view(),
        name='products_update'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/delete/$',
        ProductsDelete.as_view(),
        name='products_delete'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/copy/$',
        ProductsCopy.as_view(),
        name='products_copy'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/report/$',
        ProductsReport.as_view(),
        name='products_report'),
    url(r'^joint_products/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-][^_]+)/add/$',
        JointProductsCreate.as_view(),
        name='joint_products_create'),
    url(r'^joint_products/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
    JointProductsDetail.as_view(),
    name='joint_products_detail'),
    url(r'^joint_products/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/update/$',
        JointProductsUpdate.as_view(),
        name='joint_products_update'),
    url(r'^joint_products/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/delete/$',
        JointProductsDelete.as_view(),
        name='joint_products_delete'),
    url(r'^joint_products/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/copy/$',
        JointProductsCopy.as_view(),
        name='joint_products_copy'),
    url(r'^joint_products/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/report/$',
        JointProductsReport.as_view(),
        name='joint_products_report'),
    url(r'^joint_products/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-][^_]+)/$',
        JointProducts.as_view(),
        name='joint_products_list'),
    url(r'^add_to_cart/$', add_to_cart_view, name='add_to_cart'),
    url(r'^remove_cart/$', remove_cart_view, name='remove_cart'),
    url(r'^orders_week/$', orders_week_view, name='orders_week'),
    url(r'^orders_month/$', orders_month_view, name='orders_month'),
    url(r'^orders_year/$', orders_year_view, name='orders_year'),
    url(r'^bills_week/$', bills_week_view, name='bills_week'),
    url(r'^bills_month/$', bills_month_view, name='bills_month'),
    url(r'^bills_year/$', bills_year_view, name='bills_year'),
    url(r'^basket/$', basket_view, name='basket_view'),
    url(r'^cart_true_view/$', cart_true_view, name='cart_true_view'),
    url(r'^privat24/$', privat24, name='privat24'),
    url(r'^bill/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/$',
        BillDetail.as_view(),
        name='bill_detail'),
]
```

**views**

```
class JointProductsDetail(DetailView):
    model = JointProduct
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.is_ajax():

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.is_ajax():

    def order_form_valid(self, form, order):

    def form_valid(self, form, order, object_item):


def add_to_cart_view(request):
```

Comment: Is there a correct url in rendered page? What happens when you open this url manually? How do you check django enters this view code or not?

Comment: I get Products(ListView) view, when I open this url manually

Comment: How fix it?...(

Comment: @IvanStarostin No. I get this view ( `add_to_cart` ), when I open this url manually

Comment: @IvanStarostin If I write /add_to_cart/ I get `add_to_cart` view, but this is bad practice.